# xcode navigation title write programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"My Title";
self.title = @"JAJAJ";
```

I used this codes but not work. Most of time i use this code and was work. But now not work any idea ?

Comment: Which title is displayed when you use this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write either

```
self.title = @"JAJAJ";
```

in your `init` method of your view controller (not in `viewDidLoad`),

or override:

```
- (UINavigationItem*) navigationItem
{
    UINavigationItem* item = [super navigationItem];
    item.title = @"MY Title";
    return item;
}
```

both works.

For explanation, see [Apple's Documentation on navigationItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationItem)

Comment: `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
     if(self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
             self.title = @"My Title";
     }
     return self;
}` like this ?

Comment: I'd do it like this: `- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
 self = [super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil bundle: nibBundleOrNil];
 if (self != nil) {
  self.title = @"My Title";
 }
 return self;
}`

Comment: is that method called when putting a breakpoint in it? Else try `-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` instead. By the way: is your viewController embedded in a navigation stack of a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the solution, or post an answer including your solution? Maybe this can help others to solve their problem.